# how to update column from multiple table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys,  I want to update columns from two tables.

For example:  `abc` and `xyz`. The `abc` table contains fields called `id`, `fname`, `lastname`, `status`. And the table `xyz` contains `id`, `x_id` and `status`. Now what I want is to update a column status from `abc` and `status` column from `xyz` by using single query.

I try this query, but it is not working.

```
UPDATE abc a1 
JOIN xyz x1 ON a1.id = x1.x_id 
SET a1.status = "D" , 
    x1.status = "delete" 
WHERE a1.id = 15 AND x1.x_id = 15;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871537/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement

Comment: +1 for linking to relevant links

Answer (score 0):

Edited for 3 tables:

```
UPDATE a1,x1,s1 
SET a1.status = "D" , 
x1.status = "delte",
s1.status = "D" 
WHERE a1.id = x1.x_id
AND a1.id = s1.s_id 
AND a1.id = 15;
```

Comment: hey Bojan can we do this with 3 tables?

Comment: should work with same syntax (ofc with all connections between tables in WHERE statement

Comment: suppose i added new table called srk with fields id, s_id and status then how i find common field in WHERE CLAUSE

Comment: UPDATE a1,x1,S1 
SET a1.status = "D" , 
x1.status = "delte" ,S.status = 'D'
WHERE a1.id = x1.x_id 
AND a1.id = 15 
AND x1.x_id = 15;

Comment: what is s_id? foreign key to what table?

Comment: i write like where a1.id = x1.id and a1.id = s1.id but its not working.

Comment: then you need to have WHERE a1.id = s1.s_id (primary to foreign key)

Comment: please try to learn database concepts and connection between tables.

Comment: when connecting few tables you only need to connect primary key with foreigh key that is connected to it. It is easy when you learn concept. And for exact SQL command you need to know what values you wants to update and how are tables connected. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your mysql server cannot update two tables in a single query using SQL.
You can use LOCK TABLES command to avoid race condition :

```
LOCK TABLES abc WRITE, xyz WRITE;
update abc set status = "D"  where id = 15;
update xyz set status = "delete"  where x_id = 15;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Regards,
Omar