# MySQL Update Multiple Fields with Same Value

Tags: mysql

I have two fields in two seperate tables that need to be updated to the same value. Without procedures, etc. Is this possible in a single query?

Working statement:

```
UPDATE product,product_shop SET
 product_shop.price='737.96',
 product.price='737.96',
 product_shop.wholesale_price='479.67',
 product.wholesale_price='479.67'
WHERE 
 product_shop.id_product=product.id_product AND
 product_shop.id_product=14;
```

What I was hoping for:

```
UPDATE product,product_shop SET
 product_shop.price=product.price='737.96',
 product_shop.wholesale_price=product.wholesale_price='479.67'
WHERE 
 product_shop.id_product=product.id_product AND
 product_shop.id_product=14;
```

Comment: You are doing it in the a single query (working statement)!

Comment: This might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query

Comment: or this might also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871537/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Your "working query" is the best you can do.

Comment: check this link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-update.html

Answer (score 7):

MySQL docs state you can do [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-update.html), if you are trying to avoid printing the value twice you could do the following:

```
UPDATE product,product_shop SET
 product_shop.price='737.96',
 product.price=product_shop.price, 
 product_shop.wholesale_price='479.67',
 product.wholesale_price=product_shop.wholesale_price
WHERE 
 product_shop.id_product=product.id_product AND
 product_shop.id_product=14;
```

Comment: Isn't `product.price` will refer to the old value of `product_shop.price`?